# How can I use MuleSoft for free

Tags: integration, mulesoft

I've looked at the MuleSoft website, and it's heavy on the marketing speak and wizzy sounding product names.

I'd like to cut through the fluff and get some straight answers:

1. What combination of MuleSoft software would allow me to design and run integrations for free?
2. What do I need to download to design/build solutions using MuleSoft?
3. What do I need to download to run the solutions?
4. What are the limitations of their free offerings?

**My preference would be for a detailed canonical answer**

Any blog posts, articles regarding how to set-up and use their free offering would be also useful.

Comment: You can always drop a mail to your account manager for a demo instance of mulesoft for you to play with.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal my last few requests for information went nowhere :(

Answer (score 3):

> ..overloaded with ..and wizzy sounding product names..

I am sure marketing is hurt.

Are you looking for this? https://developer.mulesoft.com/download-mule-esb-runtime

If I am starting up, I would look at the free trial first - https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/login/#/signup?apintent=generic.

Features compared b/w versions -

- https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise
- https://www.whishworks.com/blog/mulesoft/mule-esb-community-vs-enterprise-edition

Comment: Thanks for responding to some of my questions. Also, The free trial is for their paid only cloud-based platform, so it not relevant to my question.

Comment: @Robs Don't expect to get mulesoft for free. Salesforce did not purchase it to give the technology away without making money on it.

Comment: @crmprogdev you are right I don't expect their cloud offering to be free. But I am aware there was a community version. And I'd like to get a clear understanding of what's available and how to use it. All in one clear answer, so that everyone in the community can benefit :)

Comment: @Robs I just returned from DF18. There were TONS of sessions on MuleSoft where Salesforce Marketing was targeting it for different market segments making it appear as though the same product was unique for each segment's needs! Good luck! We all know that any integration is going to be customized for the situation. Nothing else is new. Same product, different branding, LOTS of HYPE!